# Orbeon forms - customize section repetitions by expression

Tags: orbeon

I have a text filed X. If X field is empty I want to set section Y repetitions to 1. If X field is not empty I want to set section Y repetitions from 0 to 1.
I tried to customize it in section repetitions like this:

[image]

Link to form: https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/485d30b47d4f7a5f7dde7674b4d53eeb5a390436

Expected behaviour:

- if field X is not empty, section Y is optional (0 or 1 repetition); user can remove section
- if field X is empty, section Y is required (1 repetition); user can't remove section
- if section Y has 0 repetition and we remove value from field X then create one section Y repetition

Is it possible to do that in Orbeon?

Comment: Good question; I posted a suggestion on how to handle this as an answer below. Does it sound like this could work for you? -Alex

Comment: Just curious, @m.makos, did you get a chance to try my suggestion below, using a checkbox to control whether the section is shown, and a plain section instead of a repeated section? ‑Alex

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the min/max setting for repeated content for repeated grids or repeated sections impacts the user's ability to add/remove rows/sections, but not the validity of the form should the number of rows/sections be below the minimum or above the maximum. This is covered by [RFE #4567](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4567).

While what you suggest might be possible in the future, I think it is better, for usability, to handle this in a more explicit way:

1. Have a checkbox (e.g. "Provide additional information"), which is only shown if the text field isn't empty.
2. Create a non-repeated section, and set it to be visible if the field is empty *or* the checkbox is checked.

Comment: I used the advice number 2. I created 2 sections: first non-repeated section (1 repetition);  second repeated section (0 or 1 repetition). Basing on value from field X, I set sections visibility (hide or show). But this is not a perfect solution, because I have to create one redundant section.

Comment: @m.makos Why do you need the "second repeated section (0 or 1 repetition)"? Isn't it enough to just have 1 section (non-repeated) for which you set the Visibility in the Section/Grid Settings? https://i.imgur.com/93QMwLo.png ‑Alex

Comment: I wrote in my question: if field X is not empty, section Y is optional (0 or 1 repetition); user can remove section. In this scenario user can choose, if he want to fill this section or not (optional section). So this section must be set repetitions from 0 to 1.

Comment: @m.makos Got it, but in my response I was suggestion to use a regular (non-repeated) section, hide it when needed using the Visibility formula? Have you tried this? With this, you wouldn't need a repeated section (for this at least). Does this make sense, or am I missing something?

Comment: If field X is not empty the section must be optional (very important). User can fill this section. If user don't want to fill it, he can remove whole section. I understand that you can think your solution makes more sense but I have guidelines that I have to stick to.

Comment: @m.makos Ok, if using a repeated section works for your users, then I have no problem for it. It just seemed to me that using checkbox to let users control whether they want to fill the section or not would be a better UI for users than using the repeated section, but of course this is really up to.